# If there is no content exclusive to Registered Users, is using "Sign in with Google" etc beneficial?

Tags: javascript, authentication, web, forms-authentication, firebase

I'm developing a site that will serve as a storefront for a product. If users purchase the product, they  will need to create an account, fill out credit card information, shipping/billing address, etc. They will be able to login to the future to see past orders. Otherwise, the site should be completely navigable for any and all users. My question is: Is there any benefit that logging users in with Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc. has in this case? Would it suffice to just create my own custom login form and user accounts? The only benefit I can think of would be to already have information filled out on an order form based on the info that Google/Facebook might have - I'm not even sure if this is a capability. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is basically "is there a reason to use social network sign in instead of a custom sign in system". The answer is yes. The amount of time the teams involved in the API's and such have spent on security concerns is way longer than you could even approach on your custom implementation. So yes, you should use sign in with google.

Comment: Are security concerns the only reason to favor social network sign-in?

Comment: There may be more reasons, but I doubt any of them are more important.

Comment: Convenience, simplicity, not re-inventing wheels, utilizing existing technologies, preventing an extra password to remember, no registration process, to name a couple.